# Get all possible $_GET parameters from URL

Tags: php, url, get

I have link to a website that runs a php code with the following variable:
`http://www.example.com/run.php?test=abc`

There are other $_GET variables usable in the link other than `test`, say `id` and `title`, which I don't know about. Is it possible to get the missing variables (If there are any)? In my example case it would be the `id` and `title` variables.

Comment: No - it would be an enormous security risk if there were a general way of establishing which parameters a given URL accepted. You'd need to have familiarity with the web service the variables are feeding - in other words, know the API.

Comment: with `$_GET` you will get all parameters array from url

Comment: @Utkanos That is the answer that I'm looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

So it will hold all the url parameters. You can see this by doing:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Then you can do something with your $_GET parameters like so:

```
foreach ($_GET as $getParam => $value) {
    echo $getParam . ' = ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

`$_GET` is an array.

So `$_GET[0]` could be the value of test
`$_GET[1]` could be the value of title

So what you need to to is find out how many values are held in the `$_GET` array or loop through the array:

```
foreach ($_GET as $getParam => $value) {
    echo $getParam . ' = ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also, if your do `print_r($_GET);` you can see how all the different entries in the array.

Comment: You could at least change the variable names of my example.

Comment: Your example didn't really explain what was going on. I see you edited it later on to give an explanation. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `array_keys($_GET)` will give you the keys, just iterate through them